# Unable To Display text on UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am Trying to display a text on my `UITextView`. I am doing this to display the text

```
[_txtViewForScore setText:[_txtViewForScore.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Score:\n%@\n\n", str]]];
```

Its not displaying anything on the `UITextView` and I have no idea why. Can anyone please help me?

This is how i have connected it

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtViewForScore;
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if `_txtViewForScore` is `nil` or not?

Comment: Check your nibs are connected up and you have initialised the property - can you post the output of `NSLog(@"%@", _txtViewForScore);` ?

Comment: Are you appending text already in the textView? Or is it empty when you add the string?

Comment: @Logan its empty when i am adding the string.

Comment: I connected the textView with my code

Comment: Then, unrelated, but just wanted to point out using the string by appending string is unnecessary just use `[_textViewForScore setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Score:\n%@\n\n", str]];`  I know this isn't your problem specifically, but thought you should know.

Comment: Did you connect it by dragging the TextView over the @property? Or did you just write the IBOutlet yourself?

Comment: i dragged the textview ti the viewController.h file and the iboutlet was there.

Comment: @Logan Thanks For the Suggesttion

Comment: where is the code put?