# Unable to display text in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

Hey I am trying to display a score in a `UITextView`, but it is not being displayed.

Below is the code that i am writing in my `viewDidAppear` method:

```
[_tvScore setText:[_tvScore.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n My Score: %@", dispStr]]];
```

here the `dispStr` has the score in it and i am storing score like this:

```
dispStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",scoreTemp]];
```

but its not displaying the score on the screen. It does display the My Score but not the score. Can any one help me with this? :-/

Comment: Are you using interface builder or creating your label programmatically? What happens if you `NSLog` the value of `dispStr` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: @JMarsh i am doing is using interface builder. and i initiating dispStr in viewDidLoad and i am adding the value in dispStr in a function and then i want to display this string dispStr in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Eerily exact copy of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22417255/2611971

Comment: You asked the other question as well, please refrain from re-asking the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that "My Score" is displayed proves that this is in fact working: you are displaying text in your text view, which is what you want to do. The problem is solved - there is no problem.

Now, you are also having a different problem (which is not evident from the title of your question): you are not forming the text you want to form. You are forming "My Score" but the value of `dispStr` is evidently the empty string. This in turn is probably because `scoreTemp` is empty or is not a number. You can easily using stepping in the debugger, or logging with NSLog, to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced such kind a problem and I solved it by changing:

```
[tvContent setText:@"This is a content test."];
```

**to**

```
tvContent.text = @"This is a content test.";
```

At first I thought the problem was with not having my UITextView loaded.
But after I made sure it was loaded and connected in the interface builder, I could only set its content by doing direct attribution instead of calling setText.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check `scoreTemp` in `viewDidAppear` in `NSLog` If this gives you some result I hope that you will find the solution.

If you find `scoreTemp`  null then check where you are setting its value.